# GitLab CI - separate environments deployment and semantic release

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, semantic-release

I am trying to follow GitLab flow with staging and production environments. I also want semantic-release plugin for both environments (with this I also **need** a branch for every environment so semantic-release could work, right?)

I have successfully made semantic-release working for staging branch, it creates `vX.X.X-rc.x` as expected and it also generates changelog. Great!

But how should I properly work with those branches? I think I understand how would I do that with only master branch and two environments, but I couldn't find any info about doing this with separate branches.

I create feature branch, finish feature, merge to master. Now what? Should I have deployment job, which on every merge to master automatically merges master to staging, runs semantic-release and then deploys it? And then have manual deployment which automatically merges staging to production, runs semantic-release and then deploys production?

And second think: how would I deal with forced commit message conventions? If I am merging feature to master, there is commit message `feat(x): something something`. But what should be in those automatic master to staging and staging to production merges?

Comment: Not sure if it's convention, but I have a dev branch which does not trigger SR, a master branch (for real releases). I work from dev (with feature branches merging to dev). I'll then merge from dev into my "release" branches (master, beta, alpha, release-candidate, or vX.Y.Z for maintenance branches)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne thank you for point, this also looks good. I am reading about CI/CD for the first time (for 3 days in a row) and all I have found were just brief "examples" either about branch flow or about CI or about commit message conventions - but not everything together.
I don't even know how many things should be automated there (in ideal CI) - I mean those merges etc.

Comment: The branch-per-env is not a great approach to this problem in my opinion. I would recommend against trying to automate merges. You're going to run into a lot of pain points. You can have (manual) jobs for pushing artifacts to various environments and/or jobs that run only when there is a tag matching a semantic version pattern. In general, I'd say things work best if you only release from the default branch.

Comment: @sytech Thank you, I have spent another whole day by studying semantic-release and I think I understand it now better.
With only one release branch you mean both testing and production deployment, right? What version should I assign to test version? I thought prerelease setting in semantic-release is perfect solution for me, that would be for ex. v1.3.2-rc.2, but it works differently than I thought.

Comment: I have an idea - let's say I have short-lived branch fix/somebug and when I create PR to master, I would trigger test deployment using GitLab's dynamic environments. That would work I guess - but still, what version I would assign to it? I believe it doesn't matter here, but still something would be better than 0.0.0.